# Gas bags as insulation

Tags: creature-design, aliens

I know that gas can be a bad conductor of heat and small air pockets help with some fur coats. But what if an organism had big natural bags full of gas on its body. Would that be an effective means of insulation from the cold?

Comment: Many polar birds and mammals use air *trapped* by fur and feathers as quite effective insulation. One problem with a gasbag is that you still have living, vulnerable tissue on the external side of the insulation.

Comment: @user535733 Unless it's a disgusting bubbling mucous instead

Comment: @DKNguyen mucous is wet though so will increase heat loss through evaporation

Comment: @jk. Surely some, but I think there are some surprisingly dry oily forms of mucous. But then it's a tradeoff between ruggedness and performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really with large pockets, only with very small ones. If gas alone was a good insulator per se, we wouldn't need coats in winter, there is plenty of air already. Gas is a good insulator when contained in small pockets, else through convection takes away heat.

The reason for the need of small pockets is that, once convective flow develops in the gas, if the volume is small enough one side of the convective cell will interfere through viscosity with the other side, preventing the onset of the flow and thus letting the gas dissipate heat only through conduction, which is less effective than convection.

And that's precisely the reason why wool is insulating: it has a small pocket of air in its fiber

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but might get in the way of other survival activities though. Also, probably rather delicate. Fur and feathers tends to be more durable.